# Divide one column into many - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select, case

I have a column called @months which stores months in this format

> @month = '01-03-05-11-12'

**I would like to have a SELECT query that divides this column into 12, making it Jan, Feb, March**

Each of my record has this column in front. So if a record has @month = '01-03' in it, it shows under January and March. Can something like that be done? Or anything close is good enough.

I played with case statement but could not produce the results.

---

Code if anyone wants to try

```
create table recs(
id int not null primary key,
cust_name varchar(20),
callmonth varchar(36)
)

insert into recs values(1,'john','01-12')
insert into recs values(2,'Jessica','02-06')
insert into recs values(3,'Charlie','01-06')
insert into recs values(4,'steale','03-04')
insert into recs values(5,'Silica','01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-12')
insert into recs values(6,'Luder','01-03-05-07-09-11-12')
insert into recs values(7,'Panther','01-06-12')
insert into recs values(8,'Dinky','03-04-15')
```

Comment: Why are you storing delimited strings in an RDBMS?

Comment: Bad bad bad design... Fix your table structure instead of flailing around in the dark trying to compensate for this mis-design decision.

Comment: you mean, I should have 12 different columns for each month?

Comment: I'll explain it a bit more: I have 20k records, each record has a scheduled month to be called every year. There is another table that keeps records of calls made. So far the logic is working for me to trace back records for every month in the current and past year? What am I doing wrong and to fix it. And this query is only for *myself* for testing purpose, not to be implemented in the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be unclear about what you are trying to do, but you can devide into 12 tables using the following:

```
INSERT INTO January_table
SELECT *
FROM Original_table
WHERE month LIKE '%01%';
```

Do this for each month and it should give you 12 tables containing only the values that have that month.  You could then use a view to combine them.

Alternatively, if you are looking for one query, you might be able to use a case statement like the one below:

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT *
    CASE
    WHEN month LIKE '%01%' THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
    END,
    CASE
    WHEN month LIKE '%02%' THEN 'True'
    ...
FROM Original_table;
```

This will yield a table with all fields from the original table, followed by 12 "monthly columns" each with a true or false representing whether that month is present in that row.

Comment: Oh I wanted to avoid 12 query's, that's why I posted the question :)

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done with only 1 query. Or, at least, on query that is not extremely complicated.  I would recommend permanently restructuring the tables so that there are, as you are asking, 12 columns, each with a boolean value.  It may take 12 queries to do this, but its 12 queries you will only execute once, then future work will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

you should split the values by '-'  - and then youll have a table

and then you should see if that value is inside this table + its string name.

p.s.

You have to hav a table like this :

```
01 - jan
02 - feb
...
...
```

let say : 
table months ( **TBLMNTH**)  will have `( id , name )`

e.g. :

```
1 |   jan  
2 |   feb
select name from  TBLMNTH where @month CHARINDEX(name , @month)>-1
```

Comment: But I am talking a query. I am doing this for some analysis. The rest of the implementation is done. I need just query.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with other posters - you should change your table design -as you have it it is very poor form.

your case statement should generally be of this form:

```
case when instr(month,'01') > 0 then 'Jan'
```

Comment: `instr` is not a recognized function, do I have to define this myself? - Thanks

Comment: MS SQL equivalent of Oracle `InStr` is CharIndex btw, still did not work though but the syntax is nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Create SPLIT function and use it with DATENAME as below , you can get list of months in string format..I think this will solve part of your problem.

```
select  DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, convert(int, val) , -1 )) AS month_str 
from  SPLIT('01-03-05-11-12', '-')
```

Result will be (tested in mssql server;it's working)

```
January
March
May
November
December
```

> UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT
(
 @s nvarchar(max),
 @splitChar nchar(1)
)
returns @t table (id int identity(1,1), val nvarchar(max))
as
begin

declare @i int, @j int
select @i = 0, @j = (len(@s) - len(replace(@s,@splitChar,'')))

;with cte 
as
(
 select
  i = @i + 1,
  s = @s, 
  n = substring(@s, 0, charindex(@splitChar, @s)),
  m = substring(@s, charindex(@splitChar, @s)+1, len(@s) - charindex(@splitChar, @s))

 union all

 select 
  i = cte.i + 1,
  s = cte.m, 
  n = substring(cte.m, 0, charindex(@splitChar, cte.m)),
  m = substring(
   cte.m,
   charindex(@splitChar, cte.m) + 1,
   len(cte.m)-charindex(@splitChar, cte.m)
 )
 from cte
 where i <= @j
)
insert into @t (val)
select pieces
from 
(
 select 
 ltrim(rtrim(case when i <= @j then n else m end)) pieces
 from cte
) t
where
 len(pieces) > 0
option (maxrecursion 0)

return

end

GO
```